# Align input fields in a fieldset

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having a selection input fields in a fieldset and a submit button.All the programming logic were completed to make it work as desired.But i am currently facing an uphill task of aligning the input fields so that it can look stylish and comfortable to the user's eyes.I am new to CSS and any help /suggestions to make the screen visually convincing are welcome.

```html
<fieldset>
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" vspace="0" hspace="0">
    <tr>
      <td align="left">Student ID: #:
        <select name="ID" size="1">
          <option>Select ID</option>
          <option>SE45</option>
          <option>SE46</option>
          <option>SE47</option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <td align="left">Subject:
        <select name="subject" size="1">
          <option>Select Subject</option>
          <option>Science</option>
          <option>Maths</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left">Class:
        <select name="class" size="1">
          <option>SEC2A</option>
          <option>SEC2B</option>
          <option>SEC2C</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <input type="button" value="submit" />
    </tr>
  </table>
</fieldset>
```

After giving a wider search on the alignment of input fields topic , i am presented with only few of the search results and all are not completely useful.

So I want to make this post useful for the stackoverflow readers and you can share any of the suggestions related to the alignment of the input fields

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jaggs/wdzgm1x0/

Comment: Why was there a down vote to this question?The question might look so simple .But there are lot of answers to this question which can provide a novice like me a lot of options to style and align a form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
fieldset {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}
td {
  padding: 5px;
}
#submit-btn {
  color: white;
}
select{
  width: 100px;
}

label{
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" vspace="0" hspace="0">
    <tr>
      <td align="left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="ID">Student ID: #:</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="ID" size="1">
            <option>Select ID</option>
            <option>SE45</option>
            <option>SE46</option>
            <option>SE47</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
      <tr>
        <td align="left">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="subject" size="1">
              <option>Select Subject</option>
              <option>Science</option>
              <option>Maths</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="class">Class:</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="class" size="1">
            <option>SEC2A</option>
            <option>SEC2B</option>
            <option>SEC2C</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Submit" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Bootstrap sounds great.But i am planning to do it with just CSS and no addons

Answer (score 0):

```
<fieldset>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" vspace="0" hspace="0">
<tr>
  <td align="left">Student ID: #:</td>
  <td><select name="ID" size="1">
  <option>Select ID</option>
  <option>SE45</option>
  <option>SE46</option>
  <option>SE47</option>
</select>
</td></tr>

<tr><td align="left">Subject:</td><td>
<select name="subject" size="1">
  <option>Select Subject</option>
  <option>Science</option>
  <option>Maths</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left">Class:</td><td>
<select name="class" size="1">
  <option>SEC2A</option>
  <option>SEC2B</option>
  <option>SEC2C</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
 <tr><td colspan=2>
   <input type="button" value="submit" />
 </td></tr>
 </table>
 </fieldset>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.I have tried your suggested code and the alignment is even worse.can you show me with an fiddle ?

Comment: That helps a lot .Thanks.But i want the input fields alignment o be more attractive visually.